# Not getting suggestions in vs code for newly created extension

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

My code is as follows:

```
/**
 *  Input auto-completion provider
 */
class InputAutoCompletionProvider {
  // eslint-disable-next-line class-methods-use-this
  provideCompletionItems(document, position) {
    const lineAt = document.lineAt(position);
    const lineText = document.getText(lineAt.range);

    const searchText = getSearchText(lineText, position);

    const items = [];
    // console.log('lineAt', lineAt);
    // console.log('lineText', lineText);
    // Add the actual typed text to suggestions list
    const item = new vscode.CompletionItem(kh2dev(searchText));
    item.sortText = String(0);
    console.log(item);
    items.push(item);

    return items;
  }
}

module.exports = InputAutoCompletionProvider;
```

The rest is hosted at [github](https://github.com/eadaradhiraj/kyoto-harvard-transliteration)

The intention is run the transliteration and show it in suggestions. The objective is to select that transliteration in the suggestion to replace the word.

I can get the right output in the console while debugging but not in the suggestions tooltip while activating the extension.

Comment: what is `searchText` and what is result of `kh2dev(searchText)`

Comment: searchText is the word before the cursor. kh2dev does some transliteration. I could add it but I was warned that the question would be too long

Comment: i based my code on this https://github.com/varunkumar/google-input-tools.

Comment: yes, I saw in the code but you don't log the values so you don't know if they have what you expect

Comment: does it work if you debug the code of `google-input-tools` as source

Comment: Yes perfectly. In fact the base code by varun worked. But when I test out my new extension it doesnt. I type out a word and press ctrl+space. `No suggestions`. I used `console.log` to print out the values and they are correct

Comment: no need to type ctrl+space, the completion provider is called while typing

Comment: But I cant see the suggestions in the editor?

Comment: does the completionitemprovider example work, if yes slowly modify it to what you want and test at each step to see when it stops working

Comment: I tried everything

Comment: Have you tried logging the items count before and after the push just to ensure something wacky isn't going on with the items collection. Granted, it's hard to imagine push failing, but the only way to be absolutely certain is to log, log, log.

Comment: I am only sending one item. I can see it in the debug console. But not in the list of suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cloned your repo and worked it out.

Short answer: Add this to your code:

```js
    item.filterText = searchText;
    item.preselect = true;  // this sometimes helps
```

Longer answer:

I remembered that sometimes you have to add a `CompletionItemRange.range` even if you think the default would work.  So I tried

```
item.range  = new vscode.Range(position, position);
```

and indeed, now your desired completions do show up.  But they are put at the very end of the suggestions so one would usually have to scroll to see them.  And worse, selecting them only put them at the cursor position - it did not replace the letter that triggered the completion.  That probably isn't what you wanted.

I found this GitHub issue: [CompletionItems and ranges not working](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/138723#issuecomment-989713095).  Here is the relevant part in full:

> A completion item provider is invoked, returns completions but they
> don't show up!  What's the issue? Filtering! Filtering compares
> completions with a prefix and hides those that don't match.
>
> ###### Example

- trigger completions here: `say.he|` (`|` is the cursor)
- provider returns `abc`, `help`, `hood`
- the editor takes the `he`-prefix and scores it against `abc`, `help`, and `hood`.
- scoring yields these result:
  `abc` - no match, don't show
  `help` - good match, show
  `hood` - no match, only `h` occurs, don't show
- editor shows help suggestion, does not show `abc` and `hood` suggestion

> ###### Extensions Rule!
>
> The above sample was using "defaults" to determine the prefix and the
> filter criteria.
>
> - `prefix`: each completion can define its very own prefix via `vscode.CompletionItem#range`. Taking the example above, valid
>   prefixes can be `say.he` or `.he` or ``  (the empty string). Any range
>   is valid as long as it includes the cursor position and is single line
>   only.
> - `filter`: each completion can define what string to use when filtering. The default is the label but via
>   `vscode.CompletionItem#filterText` any string can be defined
>
> When to use what? It depends on the language, its word definition, and
> if you control/understand the word definition or not. The defaults
> usually work well enough but some languages might use a non-intuitive
> word definition, or completions span multiple words, or completions
> include non-word character etc. In all those cases the
> `range`-property should be used.

I examined the suggestion score of your completions.  Select one of your suggestions and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>. I use this keybinding in the DEMO below.

Your completions had a score of -100 no surprise why it was put at the end of all suggestions.  But it had no `prefix` value at all which explains why accepting the completion did not replace the current letter that triggered it.

Reading through the above GH quote implies using either `item.filter` or setting a `prefix`.  But there is no `prefix` property - you set the `prefix` by setting the `range`.  I had already tried setting the `range` and while it did show the completion it didn't actually replace the trigger letter.

So I tried

item.filterText = searchText;

Now that sets the `prefix` to the trigger character, say `a` and the score is much higher since the `prefix` is being matched against the `leading word` which is also the trigger character.

##### IMPORTANT

Using `*` as the `DocumentSelector` in `registerCompletionItemProvider()` does not work for me.  If you want to target all files this does seem to work but for performance reasons you should list the fileTypes if possible rather than targeting them all:

```js
        const provider = new InputAutoCompletionProvider();
        disposableProvider = vscode.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider(
          // '*',    // doesn't work
          { pattern: '**/' },   // does target different filetypes
          provider,
           .......
```

Here is a demo:

[image: completions with filterText]